# How we can perform advanced search with case sensitive data in Dynamic 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, office365, crm

I have two fields username, and password in contact entity.

I want to search username and password with a case-sensitive password.

username: test@test.com and password: **test** should work but,

password **TEST,Test** should not work while performing an advance search.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge if this is not working for you out-of-the-box, it is not possible.

CRM depends on the SQL Server collation for text comparisons and this is set based on the default language when configuring your CRM instance.

When using English as the default language, CRM uses the `Latin1_General_CI_AI` sql collation. `CI` stands for "case insensitive" and `AI` for "accent insensitive"

Comment: Thanks for your response I would really appreciate if someone provides me the way to deal with.Thanks once again.

Comment: Yes, CRM's default SQL collation for English is Latin1_General_CI_AI. "CI" stands for case insensitive and "AI" for accent insensitive. Assuming that is the collation in effect, the out-of-box advanced find will return all instances of the string "test", regardless of casing.

Comment: Thanks @Aron, I've updated my answer with your extra information. I didn't know what "AI" meant. Something new!

Answer (score 0):

one solution I found while dealing with xml query and c# programming.

First I fetch records using xml query with username and password.

C# is case-Sensitive so after fetching record from CRM I have just compared user-entered password and database password

**Enteredpassword==Databsepassword** both same then and only then it will allow access.